# How to divide Bootstrap Modal into 4 columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I'm trying to put a `Modal` in a `button` which will display some data I put in. I've almost managed to get it working but not quite there yet. I have the following code:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="container-fluid modal-body">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
             <p>
                 c1
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>
                    c2
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>
                  c3
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>
                  c4
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problems I'm unable to solve is the fact that it is transparent, the closing button should be down right. Any ideas how to fix it?

And you can see it in action here: https://www.bootply.com/XkRrihCeJx (I put it on bootply because that's exactly how it looks on my website and it doesn't look the same using Stack Snippets. Hopefully that is ok).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>
                        c1
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>
                        c2
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>
                      c3
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p>
                      c4
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope you found the solution in this answer

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Any idea I could ask you how would I put data under the columns? Now they look like headers if you run your code to see what I mean and would love to put data under the headers.

Comment: You are welcome. check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#vertically-centered this one. you'll get the whole idea about bootstrap modal.

Comment: That's where I came from before coming to SO, anything specfic you want me to look at?

Comment: Actually inside `modal-body` you can decide how your data should be looks like. Just like you are designing in web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `container` or `container-fluid` `div` with a `row` `div` inside, and then dividing the `row` `div` setting four `col-md-3` (or `col-lg-3` depending of the viewport) inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed `.modal-content` class to add. Just add a div with `.modal-content` class after the div with class `modal-dialog`.

For example:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="container-fluid modal-body">
      ...............
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now It's not transparent anymore but this doesn't fix the rest of the issues i'm facing

Comment: For the close button, you need to move that part outside of `<div class="container-fluid modal-body"> ........... </div>` , as the `.model-footer` is inside the `.modal-body`.

Answer (score 0):

Make four columns of col-3 inside a row. (adjust col-md-3, col-lg-3 according to view port).